# Скролл блока снизу вверх при пролистывании страницы

Tags: html

Всем привет, в общем столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно сделать так что бы при пролистывании страницы блок что находится ниже верхнего(intro) налазил на первый блок при пролистывании, как это можно реализовать я вообще не понимаю.[image: пример того, что я хочу сделать]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью `z-index` в `css`. Бокс №1 зафиксируйте в одном положении, а бокс №2 пускай нормально пролистывается. В `css` первого бокса сделайте `z-index: 1;` а в `css` второго бокса сделайте `z-index: 2;`